# Wpf DataGrid bind selection from two Collections of same Count

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have `List<Foo> F` and `List<Bar> B`, same Count.
What is the cleanest/nicest way to bind columns F.x and B.y to same DataGrid in WPF and mantain OneWay binding from DataGrid to lists F and B.

Answer (score 3):

I Would create a hybrid object:

The classes:

```
    public class FooBar
    {
        public Foo F { get; set; }
        public Bar B { get; set; }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }
```

The view model:

```
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void InvokePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }

        #endregion

        public ViewModel()
        {
            this.FooBars.Add(new FooBar()
            {
                B = new Bar(){Y = 30},
                F = new Foo(){ X = 100}
            });
        }

        private ObservableCollection<FooBar> fooBars = new ObservableCollection<FooBar>();
        public ObservableCollection<FooBar> FooBars
        {
            get { return this.fooBars; }
            set
            {
                this.fooBars = value;
                InvokePropertyChanged("FooBars");
            }
        }
    }
```

The window back code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

The view:

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FooBars}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=F.X, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="This is FOO"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=B.Y, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="This is BAR"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thx for detailed explanation. I will try to use parts of this solution to enable OneWay binding form List<Foo> and List<Bar>.